# Shouldn't I be able to see private ("Stack Overflow for Teams") questions when filtering by tag?

Tags: support, tags, search, stack-overflow-for-teams

We just started using Stack Overflow for Teams. I noticed that on the main start page of SO, I see both public questions and our private team questions.

However, when I filter by a tag that exists among both public and private questions, only public questions are displayed.

Shouldn't *all* questions be visible when filtering by tag on the public SO site? I was a bit confused by the fact that our private questions were visible on the start page, but not when clicking a specific tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a bit on how you reached the tag page. If you click on a tag below a question, you will navigate to the tag page *within either the Public Q&A or the active team*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments
- https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/tagged/comments

and you'll only see questions from that specific part of Stack Overflow.

However, if you search for a tag, e.g. with the query [`[comments]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[comments]), you'll see results from all teams *and* Public Q&A.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense I guess. However, it would make more sense for me if the tag links on the public SO site would link to a search within _all_ SO sites, whereas the link tags on a Teams site would only list questions within that specific site.

Regardless, I understand the design decision, and it's clearly still possible to filter by a specific tag across _all_ SO sites. Thanks!